# Ordering rows cross-nodes in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    session_id timeuuid,
    app_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id, app_id)
)
```

To have a good data distribution across nodes, I need to have the Partition key set as the `session_id` (as I expect millions of such sessions).

How can I have DESC ordered rows when trying to fetch the sessions that fall into a specific array of session Ids? Something like this:

```
this.cassandraClient
            .query()
            .select("*")
            .from("sessions")
            .where("session_id", "in", instancesIds)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly with Cassandra, and this table design. `ASC`/`DESC` are working only inside same partition, not between multiple partitions.  You'll need to perform sort inside your client.

Comment: I was hoping for a pagination design, which would need some ordering (prior to reaching the client). Also, fetching all the entries and in the backend and returning manually ordered items is not an option

Comment: I can only suggest to put sessions into buckets by using date (full day) as partition key & session_id as clustering key - this will return data in order inside that bucket, but not when you query multiple buckets/days